# Why was my third interview cancelled and rescheduled

Tags: interviewing, job-search, recruitment, hiring-process

I recently passed two interviews with a company and these interviews were really amazing. When I told them my salary expectations, I was assured by the hiring manager that I will get much more than my expectation and he asked whether I have my driver license. He told me a lot of amazing things and made it clear that he is really impressed by my profile, previous work and last company recommendation. I was scheduled for a third interview with the Carier Head and other team members and just one hour before the interview I was told that the carier head just cancelled the third interview because he has an unexpected meeting and decided to reschedule the interview with me at a latter date. They said they will let me know that latter date ASAP.

Please has anybody had this kind of experience? And what does this means. Will appreciate your kind response to this.

Comment: Why don't you accept the explanation they gave at face value? What makes you suspicious that it isn't simply true that there was a scheduling conflict (or a last minute emergency) that required them to reschedule? Also, what is a "Carier Head"?

Comment: Either they are telling the truth, or they are lying. It doesn't matter which one it is, the decision has already been made. Up to you how you want to handle it. Maybe you wait for them to get in touch, maybe you keep looking elsewhere, maybe both.

Answer (score 8):

I have been there from the other sided, as the interviewer.

I am not HR, hiring people is not my main task. If I have an interview arranged for a given day and time and something work related comes up, I won't think too much about rescheduling the interview. It's called priority setting.

Don't worry too much and wait for their new schedule.

Answer (score 4):

The reason was there in the communication you received - the one  ("Carier Head") who was supposed to interview you, had to make a change of plans. That happens. Please do not overthink it, and wait for the revised schedule.

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple reasons the meeting could have been rescheduled:

- The person had a conflict. Sometimes people speak the truth
- They want to slow down the process because another candidate had a conflict and they want to delay all the candidates at this step of the process.
- They have decided on somebody else, they have made an offer, but want to keep you thinking you have a chance. If the person they sent an offer to says no, they will look to one of the other people on pause.

Keep applying and interviewing while waiting for the next step. Even successful hiring actions don't always move in a straight line.